# Is it possible to get the Active directory password expiration date using spring LDAP?

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, jndi, spring-ldap

I am new to `Spring LADP` . But , I have some real time experience `Spring MVC` .

Now my requirement is to check **when the password is going to expire in active directory** ?

I have searched in **google** and found some of the post to manage `Active directory` and those are very old *(appx 2 to 5 years older)*.

I didn't find solution for my requirement in http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/

Hope you people will help me to get the solution.

Suggestions are always welcome.Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution for your question. I am exactly looking any clue for same question